# Kotlin Spinner selection

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

I created a custom spinner adapter, populated with data, on runtime it drops the list, but nothing can be selected. The selection works with the stock ArrayAdapter, but the custom. Please help, what am I missig...

DetailsActivity.kt:

'''class DetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

.
.
.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.word_details)

    val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.topic_spinner)

    spinner.adapter = cAdapter(applicationContext, fillSpinner())

    val listener = object :  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View, pos: Int, id: Long) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Selected: $pos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        }
    }

    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = listener
```

.
.
.
'''

fillSpinner function:
'''

fun fillSpinner(): ArrayList{

```
    val topics = ArrayList<String>()
    topics.clear()

    val h_cursor = dbHandler.get_h_AllRow()
    h_cursor.moveToFirst()

    while (!h_cursor.isAfterLast){
        topics.add(h_cursor.getString(h_cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.H_COLUMN_TOPIC)))
        h_cursor.moveToNext()
    }

    return topics
```

}

'''

cAdapter class:

'''

class cAdapter(val ctx: Context, val items: ArrayList) :
    ArrayAdapter(ctx, 0, items) {

```
override fun getView(position: Int, recycledView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    return this.createView(position, recycledView, parent)
}

override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, recycledView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    return this.createView(position, recycledView, parent)
}

private fun createView(position: Int, recycledView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    val item = getItem(position)
    val view = recycledView ?: LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
        R.layout.spinner_layout,
        parent,
        false)

    view.IB_cancel.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete)
    view.IB_cancel.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(context, "DELETE SOMETHING!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    view.t_sp_holder.text = item

    return view
}
```

}

'''

As I see, the problem should lie somewhere here in theese lines. Please give some advice, I am new at Kotlin.